# Counting observations by 30-days window

Tags: r, tidyverse

As I explained in previous posts I'm trying to count observations over 30 days windows grouping by id.

The data:

```
df<-structure(list(id=c(1,1,1,2),date=c("2001-07-29","2001-08-01","2001-07-20","2001-07-21")))


df<-as.data.frame(df)

df<-df%>%
  mutate(date=ymd(date))
```

The code:

```
df<-df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(n=sapply(seq(length(date)),
                  function(x) sum(between(date[1:x],date[x]-days(30),date[x]))))
```

The output is wrong because the expected result is:

```
id  date    n
1   29/07/2001  2
1   01/08/2001  3
1   20/07/2001  1
2   21/07/2001  1
```

Comment: Why is your first `n` 2?

Comment: date is (dd/mm/yyyy). obs 1 is n=2 because 30 or less days before 29/07/2001 we have a obs 3 with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df<-structure(list(id=c(1,1,1,2),date=c("2001-07-29","2001-08-01","2001-07-20","2001-07-21")))
df <- as.data.frame(df)

df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  group_by(id, fl = floor_date(date - days(19), "month") + days(19)) %>% 
  arrange(date, .by_group = T) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number())

# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   id, fl [2]
     id date       fl             n
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <int>
1     1 2001-07-20 2001-07-20     1
2     1 2001-07-29 2001-07-20     2
3     1 2001-08-01 2001-07-20     3
4     2 2001-07-21 2001-07-20     1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have to `arrange` your date first and you can use the following code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(n = sapply(seq(length(date)), 
                         function(x) sum(between(date[1:x], date[x] - days(30), date[x]))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id date           n
  <dbl> <date>     <int>
1     1 2001-07-20     1
2     2 2001-07-21     1
3     1 2001-07-29     2
4     1 2001-08-01     3
```